# Python: how to sum/multiply an int with the value of a @property

Tags: python, python-decorators

The name property stands in the way here, so my searches has been unsuccessful.
What I want to accomplice is multiply (sum , subtract, ...) an integer value to a value coming from a property (meaning @property):

```
class A:
    __att = 3
    @property
    def att():
        return __att
    
    def test_method(self):
        return 3*A.att
        
a = A()
x = a.test_method()
```

but I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'property'`

I understand the meaning of the message: it's sort of trying to multiply an int to a method name instead of its result, but for properties, shouldn't it be transparent?
I do not understand what I'm missing here.

Comment: typo: should be `return 3*A.__att` not `return 3*A.att`

Comment: @OriYarden I do not want to call A.__att, I need to use the property

Comment: whoops, I misread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a class property, you can stack decorators.

```
class A:
    __att = 3
    @classmethod
    @property
    def att(cls):
        return cls.__att

    def test_method(self):
        return 3*A.att
```

The value is accessible from `a.att` or `A.att` and shared between all instances. The "real" class attribute which the property gets is name-mangled at `A._A__att`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was writing after @mipadi pointed me in the right direction, anyway accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `att` attribute of the *class* (`A.att`):

```
return 3*A.att
```

As a class attribute, `att` is indeed a `property`.

You should call `att` using the *instance* (via `self`):

```
return 3*self.att
```

---

This is tangential to your question, but `att` also needs to take a `self` argument:

```
@property
def att(self):
    return self.__att
```

Comment: As you see from my code, I can't:  "A.att() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" because att is a class property, not an instance one

Comment: @massi: `att()` needs to take a `self` argument.